# Accessing multiple elements in a 3d matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, element

```
val(:,:,1) =

0.1068    0.7150    0.6987    0.5000
0.6538    0.9037    0.1978    0.4799
0.4942    0.8909    0.0305    0.9047
0.7791    0.3342    0.7441    0.6099


val(:,:,2) =

0.6177    0.1829    0.4899    0.5005
0.8594    0.2399    0.1679    0.4711
0.8055    0.8865    0.9787    0.0596
0.5767    0.0287    0.7127    0.6820


val(:,:,3) =

0.0424    0.8181    0.6596    0.8003
0.0714    0.8175    0.5186    0.4538
0.5216    0.7224    0.9730    0.4324
0.0967    0.1499    0.6490    0.8253

Row Col    
4   1
1   2
3   3
```

Hi, i want to take multiple points from a 3d array, but i don't know any efficient methods without using loops. I've tried messing around with sub2ind but it doesn't seem very effective to do each 2d matrix separately.

Comment: Show us what you already tried...

Comment: `res = val(row,col,:);`

Comment: index = sub2ind(size(array),row,col)  then 


output = array(index)

This gives only the first 2d array values but it doesnt give the rest

Comment: @obchardon i have tried that before as well but it doesn't seem to get me what i want. I need the output to be something like this 

out(:,:,1) = 0.7791, 0.7150, 0.0305
out(:,:,2) = 0.5767, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want all values of the data in the third dimension you can easily acess it with:

`Rows = [4, 1, 3]
 Col = [1, 2 ,3]

 val(Rows,Col,:)`

Output:

`>> val([4, 1, 3],[1, 2, 3],:)

ans(:,:,1) =

    0.7791    0.3342    0.7441
    0.1068    0.7150    0.6987
    0.4942    0.8909    0.0305

ans(:,:,2) =

    0.5767    0.0287    0.7127
    0.6177    0.1829    0.4899
    0.8055    0.8865    0.9787

ans(:,:,3) =

    0.0967    0.1499    0.6490
    0.0424    0.8181    0.6596
    0.5216    0.7224    0.9730`

Comment: I think that OP want to access a 3D array with pairwise indice.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the desired output with:

```
x1 = [4,1,3];
x2 = [1,2,3];

x = val(x1,x2,:);

for ii = 1:size(val,3)
    res(:,:,ii) = diag(x(:,:,ii)).';
end
```

**Output:**

```
res =

ans(:,:,1) =
   0.779100   0.715000   0.030500
ans(:,:,2) =
   0.57670   0.18290   0.97870
ans(:,:,3) =
   0.096700   0.818100   0.973000
```

Or with `sub2ind`, and implicit expansion (matlab 2016b and newer)

```
x1 = [4,1,3];
x2 = [1,2,3];
len = length(x1);
ind = sub2ind(size(val),x1+zeros(len,1),x2+zeros(len,1),[1:size(val,3)].'+zeros(1,len));
res = A(ind)
%if you want to preserve the third dimension add: permute(res,[1,3,2])
%we can do that because an array in matlab has an infinite number of singleton dimension
```

**Output:**

```
res =

   0.779100   0.715000   0.030500
   0.576700   0.182900   0.978700
   0.096700   0.818100   0.973000
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but if i use your first technique for a very large array, it might take a long time? I'll use it for now and finish the rest of my code, and then optimise it later. Thanks heaps though!